# Django: convert .count value returned to int

Tags: python, django, types, typeerror, percentage

I have a the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to calculate the % of answers with the value "yes" for a given question object but I get the error `TypeError int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'`. Does count not return a int data type?

My view:

```
def questn(request, question_id):
    q = Question.objects.select_related().get(id=question_id)
    qc = q.answer_set.count
    qyc = q.answer_set.filter(value="YES").count
    qycp = ( int(qy) / int(qc) ) * 100
    return render(request, 'base.html', {
        'q':q, 
        'qc':qc, 
        'qyc':qyc,
        'qycp':qycp,
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke `count`:

```
qc = q.answer_set.count()
```

Adding the `()` invokes the `count` method.  Not having it makes `qc` refer to the `count` method itself.

Here is an example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.clear
<built-in method clear of list object at 0x02172198>
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.clear()
>>> a
[]
>>>
```

As you can see, the `clear` method of a list is only invoked once the `()` is added.